# Question about nowhere dense condition in Baire category theorem application

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

I'm asking a question in reference to Noah Schweber's answer in this question [can open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be written as the union of countable disjoint closed sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1964888/can-open-set-in-mathbbrn-be-written-as-the-union-of-countable-disjoint-clo?rq=1), which is itself a reference to GEdgar's answer here: [Does not exist cover of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by disjoint closed balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874462/does-not-exist-cover-of-mathbbrn-by-disjoint-closed-balls). I'm having trouble with the second condition: showing that each $\partial C_{n}$ is a nowhere dense subset of $B$.

First, a brief summary of the problem: show that no open subset $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be presented as a countable union of proper, closed and disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $U = \bigcup_{n\geq1} C_{n}$, $C_{n} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ closed and disjoint. Denote $B=\bigcup_{n\geq1}\partial C_{n}$. Then $B$ is complete, because it's closed: let $b \in U$ be a limit point of $B$, and $\lim_{n \to \infty} b_{n} = b$, $b_{n} \in B$. Then either $b \in B$ or $b \in C_{i}^{\circ}$ for some $i$. If the latter were to hold, i.e. $B(b, \varepsilon) \subseteq C_{i}$, we'd get a contradiction: since $b$ is the limit of $b_{n}$, we can find a $b_{n} \in \partial C_{k}$ such that $d(b_{n}, b)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, and so if $k=i$, we can find a point $c$ from $C_{i}^{\complement}$ such that $d(b_{n}, c)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, and so $d(b, c)<\varepsilon$, which is a contradiction. On the other hand, if $k \neq i$, then we can find a $c \in C_{k} \subseteq C_{i}^{\complement}$ such that $d(b_{n}, c) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$, which is again a contradiction. So $B$ is complete.

Here is my attempt at showing that each $\partial C_{n}$ is nowhere dense in $B$: since the boundary of a set is always closed, it suffices to show that $(\partial C_{n})^{\circ} = \emptyset$. If there were a $p \in (\partial C_{n})^{\circ}$, then $B(p, \varepsilon) \subseteq (\partial C_{n})^{\circ}$ for some $\varepsilon$, and since $C_{n}$ is closed, it contains its boundary, so $B(p, \varepsilon) \subseteq C_{n}$, so $p \in C_{i}^{\circ}$, which is a contradiction with $p \in \partial C_{n}$.

However, I've only proven that $\partial C_{n}$ is nowhere dense in $U$, and not in $B$. I'm trying to tweak my argument to make a contradiction by proving both $p \in (C_{n} \cap B)^{\circ}$ and $p \in \partial(C_{n} \cap B)$, but to no avail. Is it possible to just tweak the argument, or do I need a new one?

Since the question is 5 years old, and since my question is far too long for a comment, I've decided to open a new question instead of posting in the comments. If this does not merit a new question, I will gladly try to condense my argument/question into a comment in the original question.

Comment: I tend to remember Baire category theorem as "a complete metric space is not a countable union of closed sets with empty interior". This avoids any confusion with "nowhere dense". Clearly, the boundaries are closed, and you know they have empty interior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let me note that $B$ would not usually be complete in the standard metric. Typically, $B$ would have limit points in $\partial U$. However, since $B$ is a closed subspace of the metrisable space $U$, it's a $G_{\delta}$-set in the Baire space $U$, hence itself a Baire space.

To show that $\partial C_n$ has empty interior in $B$ (which, since the $\partial C_n$ are closed is equivalent to being nowhere dense), let $x\in \partial C_n$, and let $V$ be a small ball around $x$, so that $x \in V \subset U$. Since $x\in \partial C_n$, it follows that $W := V\setminus C_n \neq \varnothing$. Pick a $k$ such that $C_k \cap W \neq \varnothing$. Then

$$V = \underbrace{(V \cap \overset{\Large\circ}{C_k}) \mathbin{\dot{\cup}} (V \cap \partial C_k)}_{=V\cap C_k \neq \varnothing} \mathbin{\dot{\cup}} \underbrace{(V\setminus C_k)}_{\supset V\cap C_n \neq \varnothing}.$$

Since $V$ is connected, it follows that $V\cap \partial C_k \neq \varnothing$. But that means $V\cap B \not\subset \partial C_n$. Since the small balls form a neighbourhood base of $x$, it follows that $x$ is not an interior point of $\partial C_n$ relative to $B$.

And thus we have our contradiction that the Baire space $B$ is meagre in itself.